# How do I call another function in Services?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I have my main function in Services:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {1
let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
if(toNumber == "+11231231234")
 {
  const XPath = Runtime.getFunctions()['SecondFunction'].path;
  const X = require(XPath);
  X.InboundCalls(context, event, callback);

  twiml.say(`We made it back to the main function`);  
 }
```

The SecondFunction function is also defined:

```
exports.InboundCalls = (context, event, callback) => {
 let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
 twiml.say(`Second function`);

 //callback(null, twiml);
}
```

If I uncomment the callback in the second function, it says "Second function" and hangs up.

If I comment out the callback in the second function, it says "We made it back to the main function" and hangs up.

How can I get Twilio to execute BOTH functions correctly? I want to hear the phrase, "Second function we made it back to the main function."

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well that was fun. I forgot to put the "return" in front of "callback(null, twiml);" Hope nobody else ever reads this!